# Can I install java 1.6 with 64 bit on Window/Linux 32 bit?

Tags: java

Can I install java 1.6 with 64 bit on Window/Linux 32 bit?

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't install a 64-bit program on a 32-bit OS.

Comment: +1: AFAIK, You can't install any 64-bit application on any 32-bit OS, this is a limitation of the OS.